# Download file through RemoteWebDriver and chrome in headless mode

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid, google-chrome-headless

Hello i would like to ask is possible to somehow download file ex.(.csv/.pdf) on selenium node through RemoteWebDriver and in headless mode? this code below work for headless mode but i cant pass WebDriverServices to RemoteWebDriver....

```
   chromePrefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", false);
   ​chromePrefs.put("download.directory_upgrade", true);
   ​chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.enabled", false);
   ​chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
   ​chromePrefs.put("safebrowsing.disable_download_protection", true);
   ​chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
   ​ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
   ​options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
   ​if (platform.startsWith("local")) {
       ​options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
   ​} else {
       ​options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1024,768","--ignore-certificate-errors","--disable-extensions","--no-sandbox","--disable-dev-shm-usage");
   ​}

   ​caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   ​caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
   ​caps.setPlatform(getPlatform(platform));
   ​caps.setCapability(ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
   ​caps.setCapability(ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
   ​LoggingPreferences logPrefs = new LoggingPreferences();
   ​logPrefs.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
   ​caps.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, logPrefs);
   ​options.merge(caps);
   ​ChromeDriverService driverService = ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService();
   driver = new ChromeDriver(driverService, caps);

   ​System.out.println(downloadFilepath);
   ​Map< String, Object > commandParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   ​commandParams.put("cmd", "Page.setDownloadBehavior");
   ​Map < String, Object > params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
   ​params.put("behavior", "allow");
   ​params.put("downloadPath", downloadFilepath);
   ​commandParams.put("params", params);
   ​ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
   ​HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
   ​try {
       ​String command = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(commandParams);
       ​String u = driverService.getUrl().toString() + "/session/" + 
       driver.getSessionId() + "/chromium/send_command";
       ​System.out.println("U: " + u);
       ​HttpPost request = new HttpPost(u);
       ​request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
       ​request.setEntity(new StringEntity(command));
       ​httpClient.execute(request);
   ​} catch (Exception e) { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Just make sharefolder on machine where running selenium node or where have access to and set properties for downloadpath on network path

```
String downloadFilepath = "\\localhost\folderfordownload";
​chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
```