# Downloading Files with Headless Chrome - Selenium C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
 ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
           
            var chromeDriverService = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
             chromeDriverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;
             chromeDriverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
           
            options.AddArgument("--headless");
            string downloadPath = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads";
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadPath);
            options.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.default_content_setting_values.automatic_downloads", 1);
            options.AddArgument("--window-size=1920,1080");
```

For some reason I cannot download files in chrome when running headless in Selenium -

When not running in headless mode there is no issue downloading files.

Selenium Webdriver Chromedriver V110.0.5

Comment: have you tried creating chrome driver object to navigate and download the file?

Comment: Yes... I can navigate and download the file, I am not sure why I cannot do it headless

Comment: This has been addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68191130/download-file-through-remotewebdriver-and-chrome-in-headless-mode

Comment: Yes.. I am also facing issue. Found any solution?

Comment: Yes, adding "--headless=new" seems to work

Answer (score 8):

According to Selenium dev page: https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2023/headless-is-going-away/

you need to user `"--headless=new"` from now.

However, I'm still struggling with downloading files, even using this new attribute

Comment: Thank you!! I tried everything else and this is the only thing that worked.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was a bit different. However, the below code gave me the intended results.

**Refer to the below code :**

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", @"C:\Downloads");
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com/download-file");
IWebElement downloadLink = driver.FindElement(By.Id("download-link"));
downloadLink.Click();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000); // wait for awhile for 4 seconds
driver.Close();
```